# Click this button, hide info and load new info in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/tsquinn/p044mb36/

This is example html for what I'm trying to do.

```
   <ul class="pageMenu">
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Red</a></li>
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Blue</a></li>
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Green</a></li>
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Purple</a></li>
    </ul>
    <section id="contents">
        <h1>Contents</h1>
        <p>
            This is where the colored text loads. Each ".colorLink" click must overwrite the text that's here with the new text that corresponds with the link clicked.
        </p>
    </section>
    <div id="colors">
        <div class="red">
            <h2>Red</h2>
            <p>
               This is RED text!
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="blue">                 
            <h2>Blue</h2>
            <p>
                This is BLUE text! 
            </p>
        </div> 
        <div class="green">
            <h2>Green</h2>
            <p>
                This is GREEN text!
            </p>
        </div> 
        <div class="purple">
            <h2>Purple</h2>
            <p>
                This is PURPLE text!
            </p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The problem:
I need `div#colors` to be hidden when the page is loaded. Then click on a link to load the corresponding text into the contents section on the page.

I checked here and the rest of the web for answers. I found one Q&A that allowed the button pressed to show/hide a child link, but my links aren't children. I know very little JS but even playing with the code I found didn't solve the problem. I can get the buttons to toggle the corresponding text, but I couldn't get everything to hide from the start.

This is as far as I can get and I know it's not right:

```
<script>
        var removeText = document.getElementById('colors').style.display='none';            
        $(document).ready(function showLink(){
            removeText;
          $('.colorLink a').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
              var links = document.getElementsByName('ul.pageMenu li');
              var page = document.getElementsByClassName('#colors div');
              if ($(this).links == page) {
                  $("#contents")
              }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Either you forgot it or dont know it but there are parts missing in your script. Noone can help you if you provide incomplete scripts.

Comment: If `div#colors` is hidden (`display:none`) then none of the color class divs will ever show, because they are in an un-displayed container. i.e. it doesn't matter if `div.blue` is visible because it's inside an invisible container. What you want when the page is loaded is for the _contents_ of `div#colors` to be hidden, not the div itself.  You can do that with plain CSS, you don't need to use javascript to hide it: `#colors div { display: none; }` will have them hidden on load, but then you can show them later with javascript.

Comment: For some reason I didn't even think of using CSS to hide everything from the start. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on here.

First, the callback to `document.ready()` is usually anonymous, just like in your click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

Then, the values of `links` and `page` are different collections of different elements, so `$(this).links == page` will never be `true`.

Finally, you're mixing some pure javascript (`document.getElement...`),  and jquery `$(...)` which is going to hurt your head.

You can instead do something like (untested):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#colors').hide();
      $('.colorLink a').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         // re-hide the divs
         $('#colors').hide();
         // get the text of the target of the click
         var link = $(e.target).text().toLowerCase();
         // show the corresponding div
         $('#colors div#'+link).show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by getting the index. refer the working demo.hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">

div#colors div{
 display: none;
}

</style>


<body>

   <ul class="pageMenu">
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Red</a></li>
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Blue</a></li>
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Green</a></li>
        <li class="colorLink"><a href="">Purple</a></li>
    </ul>

 <div id="colors">
        <div class="red">
            <h2>Red</h2>
            <p>
               This is RED text!
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="blue">                 
            <h2>Blue</h2>
            <p>
                This is BLUE text! 
            </p>
        </div> 
        <div class="green">
            <h2>Green</h2>
            <p>
                This is GREEN text!
            </p>
        </div> 
        <div class="purple">
            <h2>Purple</h2>
            <p>
                This is PURPLE text!
            </p>
    </div> 

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$("ul.pageMenu li").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();//stop the reloading page
 var theindex = $(this).index();//get the index number of clicked li
 //alert(theindex);

 $("div#colors div").eq(theindex).slideToggle(500);//according to the clicked id show/hide div.
 
 
});



</script>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: This does help some. It doesn't re-hide the text with each click or load the text into the content section but you've given me some things to research. Thank you for your help.

Comment: no it does, when you click on a link it shows its div and when you click on the same link, it hides it's div

Comment: Here is what I've done to get it closer to where I need it to be. 

$("ul.pageMenu li").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var theindex = $(this).index()
$("#contents").hide(300);
$("div#colors div").hide(400);
$("div#colors div").eq(theindex).slideToggle(500); 
});

The only thing left to do is stop the click action on the li for the div that's showing.

Answer (score 0):

So I tinkered with the code @Anuradh S provided and came up with this to get almost exactly what I want.

```
$("ul.pageMenu li").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();//stop the reloading page
var theindex = $(this).index();//get the index number of clicked li
//alert(theindex);
$("#contents").hide(300);
$("div#colors div").hide(400);
$("div#colors div").eq(theindex).slideToggle(500);//according to the clicked id show/hide div.
```

});

The last think is to prevent the current text link from being clicked again or to stop the text from reloading.

Thanks again!